# lpinfo -m -h 127.0.0.1:631 to verfy the printer drivers available on the system

Tags: macos, terminal, printing

Can someone do me  favor and run the

> lpinfo -m -h 127.0.0.1:631

that will show the listing of all printer drivers installed on your computer.

Please tell me if you see more HP printers than what I have:

[image]

I am missing HP drivers, but that is all I got for HP with my OS X 10.8.4 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem #1

I downloaded the HP drivers (all of them)

from [HP Printer Drivers](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl907) v.2.14 for OS X

Strangely the HP drivers were not included in OS X, and nobody tells you that.

Why would Apple include like million Brother drivers and only few HP is a mystery to me!

Comment: I thought that since 10.7, adding a printer through the system prefs pane automatically polled Apple for the specific drivers for the printer.  And, to potentially answer the other question, (in my opinion) Brother has done an excellent job with standardization of their drivers (ie, one driver for most/all of their color lasers; another driver for most/all of their bw lasers).  Check the size of /Library/Printers/Brother vs the hp folder after you install them.  (Neither is as bad as the Epson set @ http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1398 , though) ;-)

Comment: Well it does not do that on my OS X 10.8.4?, it has a pre- installed printer drivers in the Library (in my case mostly Brother) and it did not go online to get it ?, so I had to do what i did to get all the HP drivers :)